# The meaning and usage of the expression "raconter de beau"

Tags: sens, usage

> En fouillant dans son bureau, j'ai trouvé cette feuille. Je me demande **ce qu'elle raconte de beau**...

I get the feeling that the "beau" here is not simply used in the sense of "bon / agréable", but rather this is a set expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your feeling is right. That's a set expression here.

The meaning is equivalent to:

> Je me demande bien ce qu'elle raconte.
>
> Je me demande ce qu'elle peut raconter.
>
> Je me demande ce qu'elle raconte d'intéressant.

Comment: Hi. In my example, the subject is a thing (feuille); Can the subject be a person as well? "Je me demande ce que Sophie raconte de beau..."

Comment: Yes, absolutely.